# How to initialize a dataframe from dictionary translated into sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas

pI do:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> aa = {"a": ["group_a", "group_b", "group_c"]}
>>> ab = {"b": ["x", "y"]}
>>> ba = {"c": ["group_b"]}
>>>
>>> c = {**aa, **ab, **ba}
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient="index")
>>>
>>> print(df)
         0        1        2
a  group_a  group_b  group_c
b        x        y     None
c  groub_b     None     None
```

But I am actually looking for a pythonic way to get:

```
   group_a  group_b  group_c  x y
a  1        1        1        0 0
b  0        0        0        1 1
c  0        1        0        0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, with `pd.crosstab`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index').stack().droplevel(1)
df = pd.crosstab(df.index, df)
df.columns.name, df.index.name = None, None

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   group_a  group_b  group_c  x  y
a        1        1        1  0  0
b        0        0        0  1  1
c        0        1        0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every value in `c` is an iterable:

```
index = c.keys()
columns = sorted(list(set(itertools.chain(*c.values()))))
data = [[int(col in c[i]) for col in columns] for i in index]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
```

output:

```
   group_a  group_b  group_c  x  y
a        1        1        1  0  0
b        0        0        0  1  1
c        0        1        0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)/[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) :

```
out = (
    df.melt(ignore_index=False)
    .pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(level=0),
        columns="value", values="variable", aggfunc="count",
                 fill_value=0).rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   group_a  group_b  group_c  x  y
a        1        1        1  0  0
b        0        0        0  1  1
c        0        1        0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was:

```
index = list(c.keys())
index.sort()
columns = list(set([item for sublist in c.values() for item in sublist]))
columns.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

for key, groups in c.items():
    for group in groups:
        df.loc[key, group] = 1
```

I guess the best solution is subjectively in terms of readability, used packages, performance... I am going to choose my favorite, but thanks all for the input.